# How can I configure npm update to update mtime of files?

Tags: npm, filemtime

`npm install` and `npm update` install files in `node_modules`. The modified timestamps of these files are not what you expect: the time that these files were last installed or updated in the local filesystem. Instead, `npm` deliberately (I think) ensures that the installed files' `mtime` value remains the same as in the source archive.

That means, it is possible to find really old files in `node_modules`:

```
$ stat node_modules/plotly.js-dist/plotly.js | grep Modify
Modify: 1985-10-26 09:15:00.000000000 +0100
```

The main issue with this is that I am using these files in a build process, which only triggers if the source file's `mtime` is more recent than the target file's `mtime`.

How can I configure `npm` to update the `mtime` of a file when it is installed or updated?

Comment: AFAIK npm doesn't provide such a feature. It has been raised previously in [issue #10052](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10052) _(Note: that's from their old/archived repo)_. You'll have to resort to a custom solution to achieve such a requirement.

Comment: FYI, since my earlier comments back in July [issue #1887](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1887) has been raised.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one is interesting...
Maybe I won't solve your problem technically, but help you get different perspective on it.

PROBLEM: npm install doesn't trigger file watcher.

Solution 1:
rm- rf node_modules (delete all npm scripts)
run npm install

Solution 2:
after npm install update you app entry point manually (src/app.js) or something similar like it.

Solution 3:
Configure your file watcher to watch changes on package.js (or package.lock.js). These files always change if you add or remove new modules.